# Number greater than 9 starts at the top and stays there

Tags: javascript

This piece of code was written by [@frank-wisniewski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7936799/frank-wisniewski):]

```
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="switch-wrapper-"] input[type=checkbox]')).forEach(function(elem){
    elem.onchange=function(){
        this.parentNode.querySelector('p').innerHTML = (this.checked) ? 'Not Visible' : "Visible";
        //when you have more than 9 cards take the number with a regex..
        var newSel = '#card-'+ this.id[6];
        document.querySelector(newSel).classList.toggle('card-disabled');
    }
});
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="switch-wrapper-"] input[type=checkbox]')).forEach(function(elem){
    elem.parentNode.querySelector('p').innerHTML = (elem.checked) ? 'Not Visible' : "Visible";
    if (elem.checked)document.querySelector('#card-'+ elem.id[6]).classList.add("card-disabled");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e5brLhyy/3/

The problem I'm having right now is that if there are more than 9 cards (and switches) it's not working properly anymore, 10+ switches do not trigger the card it's next to anymore. Instead it's only triggering the first card yet.

I know there are asked a lot of questions about something 'more than 9' but I do not get how to fix it

Does somebody know the answer? Take a look at the fiddle if you want.

Comment: You don't need to use `Array.from` on `querySelectorAll` as NodeLists already have that method.

Comment: @evolutionxbox How should I change this? Just removing Array.from gives me an error

Comment: Did you look at `newSel`'s value? `var newSel = '#card-' + this.id[6];` What do you think `this.id[6]` will return? A single character, or the rest of the ID?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Edge doesn't support `.forEach` on NodeLists. @joostdelange : you don't have to remove `Array.from` if you want to provide support on Edge too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e5brLhyy/4/)

```
var newSel = '#card-'+ this.id.split('-')[1];
```

it also run under edge...

Comment: Can't understand how you all react with great answers every time!

Comment: What is the reason you wrote it different the first time?

Comment: because you have only 9 cards,

Comment: Alright! Maybe I needed to mention earlier that the amount of cards are unknown ;)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e5brLhyy/5/)

You are selecting `var newSel = '#card-'+ this.id[6];` wrong

Your `this.id` has string `"input-11"` and your code `this.id[6];` only the 6th character of the string which is 1 (input-**1**1) in `"input-11"` that is why it is disabling the first div.

What you can do is [**split**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the id with character `-` and get the index `1`

`this.id.split('-')[1];`

> The split() method splits a String object into an array of strings by
>   separating the string into substrings.

**Here is a snippet**

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id^="switch-wrapper-"] input[type=checkbox]')).forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.onchange = function() {
    console.log(this.parentNode);
    this.parentNode.querySelector('p').innerHTML = (this.checked) ? 'Disabled' : "Visible";
    
    var newSel = '#card-' + this.id.split('-')[1];
    document.querySelector(newSel).classList.toggle('card-disabled');
  }
});
```

```css
        /*Variables*/
        
        :root {
          --white: #FFFFFF;
          --black: #000000;
          --grey-200: #EEEEEE;
          --grey-400: #BDBDBD;
          --grey-50: #FAFAFA;
          --black-transparent-800: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
          --black-transparent-500: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);
          --black-transparent-300: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
          --black-transparent-100: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
          --teal-500: #009688;
          --teal-transparent-500: rgba(0, 150, 136, 0.5);
          --teal-transparent-light-500: rgba(0, 150, 136, 0.2);
          --yellow-500: #FFEB3B;
          --teal-700: #00796B;
          --h1: 2.125em;
          --text-title: 1.25em;
          --caption: 0.875em;
          --body: 1em;
          --button-shadow: 0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
          --button-shadow-active: 0px 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
          --bubble-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28), 0 0 0 1.25rem rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.1);
          --shadow: 0px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
          --container-shadow: 0px 7px 8px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 12px 17px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 5px 22px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
          --transition: 180ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1), color 180ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
        }
        
        .switch-wrapper {
          margin-bottom: 41px;
          margin-left: 5px;
        }
        
        .switch-wrapper p {
          display: inline-block;
          line-height: 1.5rem;
          margin: 0 1.25rem 0;
          vertical-align: middle;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          transition: var(--transition);
        }
        
        .switch-wrapper .switch {
          display: inline-block;
          position: relative;
          width: 2.5rem;
          height: 1rem;
          border-radius: 0.5rem;
          background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
          -webkit-transition: var(--transition);
          transition: var(--transition);
          vertical-align: middle;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .switch-wrapper .switch::before {
          content: '';
          position: absolute;
          top: -0.25rem;
          left: -0.25rem;
          width: 1.5rem;
          height: 1.5rem;
          background: #fafafa;
          box-shadow: var(--shadow);
          border-radius: 50%;
          -webkit-transition: left var(--transition), var(--transition), box-shadow var(--transition);
          transition: left var(--transition), var(--transition), box-shadow var(--transition);
        }
        
        .switch-wrapper .switch:active::before {
          box-shadow: var(--button-shadow-active);
        }
        
        .switch-wrapper input:checked + .switch {
          background: var(--teal-transparent-500);
        }
        
        .switch-wrapper input:checked + .switch::before {
          left: 1.25rem;
          background: var(--teal-500);
        }
        
        .switch-wrapper input:checked + .switch:active::before {
          box-shadow: var(--button-shadow-active);
        }
        
        .card-small-half-wrapper {
          float: left;
          width: auto;
        }
        
        .card-small-half-wrapper .card-small-half {
          width: 290px;
          min-height: 45px;
          margin: 20px 10px 20px 0px;
          display: block;
          box-shadow: var(--shadow);
          border-radius: 2px;
          transition: var(--transition);
        }
        
        .card-small-half-wrapper .card-small-half:first-child {
          margin-top: 10px;
        }
        
        .card-small-half-wrapper .card-small-half .action-bar {
          height: 45px;
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          padding: 0px 10px;
        }
        
        .card-small-half-wrapper .card-small-half .action-bar a {
          display: inline-block;
          align-items: center;
          text-align: right;
        }
        
        .card-small-half-wrapper .card-small-half .action-bar p {
          margin: 0 10px;
          font-size: var(--body);
          text-transform: uppercase;
          width: 100%;
        }
        
        .card-small-half-wrapper .card-small-half .action-bar .material-icons {
          margin: 0 10px;
          padding: 4px 0;
        }
        
        .options-card {
          float: left;
          width: 250px;
          height: auto;
          padding: 11px 20px;
          box-shadow: var(--shadow);
          margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
          min-height: 446px;
          border-radius: 2px;
        }
        
        .card-disabled {
          opacity: 0.3;
          pointer-events: none;
        }
        
        .display-none {
          display: none;
        }
        
        .material-icons {
          opacity: 0.54;
        }
```

```html
<div class="card-small-half-wrapper">
  <div class="card-small-half" id="card-1">
    <a href="components/">
      <div class="action-bar">
        <p>Add Page</p>
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-small-half" id="card-2">
    <a href="components/">
      <div class="action-bar">
        <p>Add Page</p>
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-small-half" id="card-3">
    <a href="components/">
      <div class="action-bar">
        <p>Add Page</p>
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-small-half" id="card-4">
    <a href="components/">
      <div class="action-bar">
        <p>Add Page</p>
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-small-half" id="card-5">
    <a href="components/">
      <div class="action-bar">
        <p>Add Page</p>
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-small-half" id="card-6">
    <a href="components/">
      <div class="action-bar">
        <p>Add Page</p>
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-small-half" id="card-7">
    <a href="components/">
      <div class="action-bar">
        <p>Add Page</p>
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-small-half" id="card-8">
    <a href="components/">
      <div class="action-bar">
        <p>Add Page</p>
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-small-half" id="card-9">
    <a href="components/">
      <div class="action-bar">
        <p>Add Page</p>
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-small-half" id="card-10">
    <a href="components/">
      <div class="action-bar">
        <p>Add Page</p>
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-small-half" id="card-11">
    <a href="components/">
      <div class="action-bar">
        <p>Add Page</p>
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card-small-half" id="card-12">
    <a href="components/">
      <div class="action-bar">
        <p>Add Page</p>
        <i class="material-icons">add</i>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="options-card">
  <div class="switch-wrapper" id="switch-wrapper-1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-1" class="display-none">
    <label class="switch" for="input-1"></label>
    <p>Visible</p>
  </div>
  <div class="switch-wrapper" id="switch-wrapper-2">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-2" class="display-none">
    <label class="switch" for="input-2"></label>
    <p>Visible</p>
  </div>
  <div class="switch-wrapper" id="switch-wrapper-3">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-3" class="display-none">
    <label class="switch" for="input-3"></label>
    <p>Visible</p>
  </div>
  <div class="switch-wrapper" id="switch-wrapper-4">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-4" class="display-none">
    <label class="switch" for="input-4"></label>
    <p>Visible</p>
  </div>
  <div class="switch-wrapper" id="switch-wrapper-5">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-5" class="display-none">
    <label class="switch" for="input-5"></label>
    <p>Visible</p>
  </div>
  <div class="switch-wrapper" id="switch-wrapper-6">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-6" class="display-none">
    <label class="switch" for="input-6"></label>
    <p>Visible</p>
  </div>
  <div class="switch-wrapper" id="switch-wrapper-7">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-7" class="display-none">
    <label class="switch" for="input-7"></label>
    <p>Visible</p>
  </div>
  <div class="switch-wrapper" id="switch-wrapper-8">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-8" class="display-none">
    <label class="switch" for="input-8"></label>
    <p>Visible</p>
  </div>
  <div class="switch-wrapper" id="switch-wrapper-9">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-9" class="display-none">
    <label class="switch" for="input-9"></label>
    <p>Visible</p>
  </div>
  <div class="switch-wrapper" id="switch-wrapper-10">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-10" class="display-none">
    <label class="switch" for="input-10"></label>
    <p>Visible</p>
  </div>
  <div class="switch-wrapper" id="switch-wrapper-11">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-11" class="display-none">
    <label class="switch" for="input-11"></label>
    <p>Visible</p>
  </div>
  <div class="switch-wrapper" id="switch-wrapper-12">
    <input type="checkbox" id="input-12" class="display-none">
    <label class="switch" for="input-12"></label>
    <p>Visible</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too, especially the clear explaination, I get what happened now!